# Check whether a directory is registered to any watcher service?

Tags: java

As part of my application, I need to register multiple directories to watcher service. Whenever there is a change in the directory, I will get notified by watcher service. My requirement is, for a given directory, is there any way to know, whether that directory is registered to any watcher service? I mean, I

```
Path path = new File("/Users/myDoc").toPath();
WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);

public static boolean isDirectoryRegisteredToAnyWatcherService(Path path){
    //Return true, if this directory is registered to any watcher service, else false.
}
```

Reference

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html

Answer (score 1):

Having some look at java.nio.file API I doubt that can be done with standard method calls. WatchService objects seems to contain the registered path within a HashMap called wdToKey in the inside; my best idea is to loop over all existing WatchService objects in your program, try to retrieve their inside content using reflection, and check whether any of them contains the concerned Path

Comment: I too searched for Java APIS, didn't find any...Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No built in method is provided as of now.

- What the actual doc makes use of is:
  private final Map<WatchKey,Path> keysToPath;
- but you can have a modified version like:
  private final Map<Path,WatchKey> pathToKeys;

which you can populate while registering the paths to watchService object.

Hence later, with just the Path object, if you get a key, means Path is registered.

Official Doc Ref:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java